# IoC Instancing dilemma shared context

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have a datacontext that i want to share with repositories. Most implementations recomment a singleton container as it saves the expense of rebuilding the entire container each time. The problem is you need to build an entire new container and all its dependencies for each related set of requests for instance:

```
 class CompanyService : ICompanyService
{
    private IUserRepository _userRepository;

    private IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;

    public CompanyService(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository,
          IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this._employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        this._userRepository = userRepository;
    }
}
```

Company service requires User and employee repositories, each one of these repositories requires a context:

```
class UserRepository : Repository<User>, IUserRepository
{
    public UserRepository(IDataContext dataContext) : base(dataContext) { }
}

class EmployeeRepository : Repository<Employee>, IEmployeeRepository
{
    public EmployeeRepository(IDataContext dataContext) : base(dataContext) { }
}
```

I want to be able to register these types with the container as follows:

```
    public WindsorContainer BuildContainer()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component.For<SqlContext, IDataContext>());
        container.Register(Component.For<UserRepository, IUserRepository>());
        container.Register(Component.For<EmployeeRepository, IEmployeeRepository>());
        container.Register(Component.For<CompanyService, ICompanyService>());
        return container;
    }
```

Then I just want to be able to resolve the Service as follows:

```
        var container = BuildContainer();
        var service = container.Resolve<ICompanyService>();
```

I know the default instancing is singleton, I want all these services including repositories to be transient, but i want to share the same context with the repositories BUT only for the particular set of requests.

EDIT: ThreadLocal or request based instancing WILL NOT WORK because when I resolve ICompanyService twice from the same thread but used in 2 contexts the thread remains the same and the instance of IDataContext will be the same however they shouldn't be.

I dont see a way to do this where the container is a singleton, the only way i see this is to use the build function to rebuild the whole container on each request and make IDataContext a singleton and everything else transient.

The other problem with this method is I cannot rebuild this container for my more expensive services that I intend to be singletons. Somehow i need to split the container into 2 parts a master containing expensive services or those I dont want to rebuild, and then a derived container that I can use in my build function that will just extend off the master and handle the context specific requests.

Am i just looking at this whole problem all wrong, can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Don't resolve ICompanyService twice - you shouldn't need to do this, and if you don't, your problem is solved. Rather, use the RRR pattern: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasePattern.aspx

Comment: Hi Mark, the problem is not with the Service, it is with the User and Employee Repository, they need to get the same instance of IDataContext

Comment: Yes, but if you only resolve once per HTTP request (which I'm assuming is the scenario here), the PerWebRequest lifetime ought to suffice...

Comment: Hi Mark, I thank you for your answer, but there is something here I'm not understanding correct:
In my example i have 1 service, depends on 2 repositories depending on 1 context. Each one of these 
objects must be transient (unique instance) except for the context which is resolved once and shared between repositories.
BUT only per service. When a call is made to the container.Resolve<Service1> if i have 1 call graph per request
this will be fine because the single context is then shared.

Comment: But what if there are 2 services so calling:
container.Resolve<Service1> will all have the same context which is correct
but then another call to:
container.Resolve<Service2> will share the same context with service1 which is wrong
these 2 services are resolved in the same thread

Comment: If i understand you correct, I need to rethink my architecture where the resolution to Service1 and Service2 
should be designed to be able to share the same context - Thanks for your suggestions so far

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. I admit that I didn't completely understand the problem first. Still: why do you need the context to be different across different services on the same thread?

Comment: Hi Mark, I thank you for your answer, I thought about what you said more and realized that what i am doing is complicating IoC beyond the point that it is viable. If i needed to do this I would probably be better off Resolving a repository or context and manually instanciating the other objects (controller/service), but you are right perhaps we are better off to keep the ioc a little simpler where one thread shares the instances and make sure the design works correct that way. One thing though is you have to make sure to dispose of your objects/connections when the thread dies.

Comment: Yes. That's where the RRR pattern comes in: always Release what you Resolve.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to provide your own UnitOfWork pattern and implement a custom lifestyle to control the life of the data context, without tying it to a thread, web-request, etc.

You would have to use a static property on your UnitOfWork class to make this work, so your unit of work might look like this:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable {
    [ThreadStatic]
    public static UnitOfWork Current { get; set; }

    private IDictionary<string, object> _items;

    public IDictionary<string, object> Items 
    {
         get { 
              if(_items == null) 
              {
                 _items = new Dictionary<string, object>();
              }
              return _items;
         }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
         Current = null;
    }

    public static UnitOfWork Start() 
    {
         Current = new UnitOfWork();
         return Current;
    }
}
```

Once you have something like that in place you could use it like this:

```
using(UnitOfWork.Start())
{
    var companyService = container.Resolve<ICompanyService>();
    // .. use company service
}
```

Lastly your custom lifestyle would look like this:

```
public class UnitOfWorkLifestyleManager : AbstractLifestyleManager
{
    private string PerUnitOfWorkObjectID = "UnitOfWorkLifestyleManager_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 

    public override object Resolve()
    {
        if(UnitOfWork.Current.Items[PerUnitOfWorkObjectID] == null)
        {
            // Create the actual object
            UnitOfWork.Current.Items[PerUnitOfWorkObjectID] = base.Resolve();  
        }

        return UnitOfWork.Current.Items[PerUnitOfWorkObjectID];
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    { 
    }
}
```

And registering your custom life style:

```
container.Register(Component.For<SqlContext, IDataContext>().Lifestyle.Custom<UnitOfWorkLifestyle>());
```